# Find my phone email. Notices

Tags: iphone

Recently Find my iphone has been sending emails after I log in to check my kids whereabouts.  Why is this now happening? Has there been a policy change?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Find My iPhone has always been sending out e-mails as confirmation to the user with the linked Apple ID that their device has been found. At least, I've always received confirmation by e-mail after using it.

If this was not the case for you or propably more users with the same question: 
-it has been changed to send e-mails more frequently after the iCloud-hack which was like a month ago.